# Leader not elected after after node goes down in SOLR

Tags: tomcat, solr, configuration, cloud, apache-zookeeper

I am using SOLR cloud with Tomcat. **When one of my leader nodes is down(e.g. Shard 1); its replica is not elected as leader, but is still up.** I am using a stand-alone zookeeper(well, 3 of them).
When I restart the failed node, the node is not visible, and still no leader for Shard 1 is elected. The replica is still up and leader-less.
This remains so even if I restart zookeeper and all nodes.

I am using SOLR 4.7.0
The setup I have is: 1 tomcat instance per shard. I have 2 shards and two replica shards. The replicas are on separate servers. I use an external zookeeper instance to manage all four nodes/cores. I have also tested with 3 external zk instances, but had the same result.

**Can anyone tell me where to look if this is a configuration issue or sounds familiar?**

Comment: Are you using the embedded zookeeper or external zookeeper instance?

Comment: I am using an external zookeeper instance for this infrastructure.

Comment: The only way I could get a leader elected again is by deleting the index and restarting both zookeeper and all tomcat servers(luckily I am in the dev and test phases right now)

Comment: I have downgraded from SOLR 4.7.0 to SOLR 4.2.1, and election is working properly again.

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded from SOLR 4.7.0 to SOLR 4.2.1, and election/node restart is working properly again. 
My guess is this problem was due an incompatibility between the newest SOLR 4.7 version and the very old zookeeper version that I was using.